# (Visual C++) making a version of the game Mastermind

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error

I'm making a version of the game Mastermind for a class. However, I have unfortunately hit a roadblock. Whenever I build the solution for the program, it compiles just fine, but I end up getting a run-time error. It says "Expression: vector subscript out of range". Does anybody know what this means and how do I fix it? Nothing I've found online so far has been helpful in any way.

Here's the code so far:
`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//This is where the User is allowed to input the numbers of the secret code
void chooseNumbers(int &howMany, int &howBig) {
int i;

vector<int> secret;

cout << "What's the secret? " << endl;
for (i = 0; i < howMany; ++i) {
    cin >> secret[i];
}

    if (secret[i] > howBig || secret[i] < 1) {
        cout << "Numbers must be between 1 and " << howBig << endl;

        cout << "What's the secret? " << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < howMany; ++i) {
            cin >> secret[i];
    }
  }
}

int main() {
    int howMany;
    int howBig;


    cout << "How many numbers? " << endl;
    cin >> howMany;

    cout << "How big can the numbers be? " << endl;
    cin >> howBig;

    chooseNumbers(howMany, howBig);

}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` operator simply returns a reference to the element at the specified position, and since there is nothing on the vector, you are outside the range.

```
vector<int> secret;

cout << "What's the secret? " << endl;
for (i = 0; i < howMany; ++i) {
    cin >> secret[i];
}
```

Instead, use `push_back`